# Webpack loader error loading bundle.js for reactjs in Django Application

Tags: node.js, django, reactjs, nginx, webpack

I have a Django application on production site and am using webpack with ReactJS. I've tried running npm run build but that doesn't do anything. Any ideas on why it's treating it as a string and not rendering bundle.js which is inside my static folder? I am using Nginx as my web server, which serves static files from that static folder inside my main web application folder. I've ran ./manage.py collectstatic and npm run build which executes webpack, so the files are there, not sure why it's just not being loaded.

[image]

Comment: When are you trying to run npm build?

Comment: on the server after i run collectstatic